# Unicode representation to formatted Unicode?

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, emoji, python-unicode

I am having some difficulty understanding the translation of unicode expressions into their respective characters. I have been looking at the unicode specification, and I have come across various strings that are formatted as follows `U+1F600`. As far as I have seen, there doesn't appear to be a built in function that knows how to translate these strings into the correct formatting for Python, such as `\U0001F600`.

In my program I have made a small regular expression that will find these `U\+.{5}` patterns and substitute the `U+` with `\U000`. However, what I have found is that this syntax isn't the same for all unicode characters, such as the zero width join that actually is supposed to be translated from `U+200D` to `\u200D`.

Because I don't know every variation of the correct unicode escape sequence, what is the best method to handle this case? Is it that there are only a finite amount of these special characters that I can just check for or am I going about this the wrong way entirely?

Python version is **2.7.**

Comment: Sorry, I'll add that in. It's Python 2.7. :)

Comment: `u'\u200D' == u'\U0000200D'`

Comment: Thanks for that! I wonder if the example I added will accept an extra zero. If that was the case maybe that could solve the non-uniform error. - Turns out that it does, as `\U00001F600` is a different character. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your most reliable method will be to parse the number to an integer and then use `unichr` to lookup that codepoint:

```
unichr(0x1f600)  # or: unichr(int('1f600', 16))
```

*Note:* on Python 3, it's just `chr`.

Comment: Thanks for these answers. It might be me, but I just tried the Python 2.7 example and it throws this error:

`unichr() arg not in range(0x10000)  (narrow Python build).` Any ideas?

Comment: What do you get for `import unicodedata; unicodedata.unidata_version` ?

Comment: Terminal says that I'm using `5.2.0`. Perhaps that's dated?

Comment: @lindsay that's a limitation of Python 2.7 in its narrow build form (which I believe is the default) - it's incapable of representing those higher number characters as a single Unicode codepoint, and needs to resort to a surrogate pair. In some version of Python 3 they fixed that problem, can't remember exactly which at the moment.

Comment: No, that's fine, it's just a crappy build of python.  Could you try `struct.pack('i', 0x1f600).decode('utf-32')` and see the result?

Comment: I just tried the `struct.pack` method. It seemed to work on that string. I'm baffled. What is going on behind the scenes there which isn't the case for `unichr`? This was my output. `u'\0001f600'`.

Comment: Using `struct.pack` is brilliant and disgusting at the same time. You should edit it into your answer. @lindsay there's no reason `unichr` couldn't do the same, it's just not good enough.

Comment: I'll leave the "disgusting" hack in the comments.  IOW, get a better build of Python :)

Comment: Thanks for these solutions. Really helps a lot. :)

Answer (score 3):

`U+NNNN` is just common notation used to talk about Unicode.  Python's syntax for a single Unicode character is one of:

- `u'\xNN'` for Unicode characters through U+00FF
- `u'\uNNNN'` for Unicode characters through U+FFFF
- `u'\U00NNNNNN'` for Unicode characters through U+10FFFF (max)

Note: `N` is a hexadecimal digit.

Use the correct notation when entering a character.  You can use the longer notations even for low characters:

```
u'A' == u'\x41' == u'\u0041' == u'\U00000041'
```

Programmatically, you can also generate the correct character with `unichr(n)` (Python 2) or `chr(n)` (Python 3).

Note that before Python 3.3, there were *narrow* and *wide* Unicode builds of Python.  `unichr/chr` can only support `sys.maxunicode`, which is 65535 (0xFFFF) in narrow builds and 1114111 (0x10FFFF) on wide builds.  Python 3.3 unified the builds and solved many issues with Unicode.

If you are dealing with text string in the format `U+NNNN`, here's a regular expression (Python 3).  It looks for `U+` and 4-6 hexadecimal digits, and replaces them with the `chr()` version.  Note that ASCII characters (Python 2) or printable characters (Python 3) will display the actual character and not the escaped version.

```
>>> re.sub(r'U\+([0-9A-Fa-f]{4,6})',lambda m: chr(int(m.group(1),16)),'testing U+1F600')
'testing \U0001f600'
>>> re.sub(r'U\+([0-9A-Fa-f]{4,6})',lambda m: chr(int(m.group(1),16)),'testing U+5000')
'testing \u5000'
>>> re.sub(r'U\+([0-9A-Fa-f]{4,6})',lambda m: chr(int(m.group(1),16)),'testing U+0041')
'testing A'
>>> re.sub(r'U\+([0-9A-Fa-f]{4,6})',lambda m: chr(int(m.group(1),16)),'testing U+0081')
'testing \x81'
```

Comment: O.P. is dealing with *text* like `"U+1F600"`.  Since it's not the Python syntax, there is a need for some parsing or conversion, no?

Comment: Thanks for those answers. Python 3.3 is sound really good right about now. I probably should be using it in all honesty. I tried using the `unichr` method beforehand but it didn't work due to the narrow build issue. I assume the Python 3 `chr` method can handle this issue.

Comment: Yeah, as @wim said i'm editing the text expression of the unicode character. Thanks for the detailed answer non-the-less! :)

Comment: @lindsay Added a regular expression to parse that syntax, but note that Python 2 has issues with U+10000 - U+10FFFF if you are using a narrow build.

Comment: @MarkTolonen thanks for adding in that answer. I'd never heard of this narrow issue until now.

Comment: @lindsay Before Python 3.3 Unicode characters were stored internally using [UTF-16LE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) encoding in a narrow build, and UTF-32LE in a wide build.  UTF-16 encoding uses one 16-bit word for Unicode codepoints below U+10000, and two 16-bit words for everything else.  So there were oddities like `len(u'\U0001F600') == 2` but `len(u'\U0000FFFF') == 1`.  `unichr()` only supported returning codepoints below U+10000 in a narrow build.  @wim's `struct.pack` trick works around that.

Comment: @MarkTolonen thank you for that in depth response! This unicode stuff is tricky, but that helps me get a better grasp of it all. :) Explains why I had gotten myself stuck trying to encode and decode these strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can look into `json` module implementation. It seem that it is not that simple:

```
# Unicode escape sequence
uni = _decode_uXXXX(s, end)
end += 5
# Check for surrogate pair on UCS-4 systems
if sys.maxunicode > 65535 and \
0xd800 <= uni <= 0xdbff and s[end:end + 2] == '\\u':
    uni2 = _decode_uXXXX(s, end + 1)
    if 0xdc00 <= uni2 <= 0xdfff:
        uni = 0x10000 + (((uni - 0xd800) << 10) | (uni2 - 0xdc00))
        end += 6
char = unichr(uni)
```

(from cpython-2.7.9/Lib/json/decoder.py lines 129-138)

I think that it would be easier to use `json.loads` directly:

```
>>> print json.loads('"\\u0123"')
ģ
```

Comment: If it's json, sure.  But who said anything about json?

Comment: @wim, you can create strings from unicode sequences and feed them to json parser